# How to delete file from specific path using sql procedure,

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Dears,
How to delete file from specific path using sql procedure,
I had a procedure that works on deleting row on sql that contain the attachments (attachment is uploaded from web page), I want to enhance the procedure to delete the attachment itself from the path
I will be very appreciated for ay help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For SQLServer 2019 and later versions you can use a system stored procedure for deleting files.

```
EXEC sys.xp_delete_files @Attachment
```

Comment: Dear Alireza Soltani, 
Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, this procedure is not stored here,
Can I create a new procedure and use it in the procedure that shown on my question screenshots and how I can do that?
Or there is a way to do that by writing the path of the attachment in the code to delete those attachments?

I will be very appreciated for any help
Thanks in Advance  

Lubna

Comment: @lubnanajeh Hey lubna. The way to delete (or store) files is easily possible with your backend language. Use DBMS only for manipulating your database, not more.

Comment: Hi @Alireza, I try to write a code that I found but it didn't work fine 'EXEC   xp_cmdshell 'DEL D:\e-HPCRC\Attachment\Request\RequestId\Attachment'' what do you think?